# How to place the caption of an image under the image self in a Report documentclass

Tags: graphics, report

How can i make it so that the caption ends under the image?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale= 0.3]{images/MRS.jpg}
\caption{A part of an MRS.}
\label{fig:MRS}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is simple: add after `\begin{figure}[h]` command `\centering` and see, if the resultat is what you looking for.

Comment: Welcome! Leave a blank line before `\caption...`.

Comment: @cfr 
Hey.. your method failed on my code apparently.. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Zarko
Hey.. your method failed on my code apparently.. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Than you have problem in your image. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle, my suggestion perfectly work:

[image]

Above image is generated by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[scale= 0.3]{example-image}
\caption{A part of an MRS.}
\label{fig:MRS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If this doesn't happen with your real image, than it has blank space on the left or right side of it. To see this, for test put `\includegraphics{...} into`\framebox{...}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\framebox{\includegraphics[scale= 0.3]{images/MRS.jpg}}
\caption{A part of an MRS.}
\label{fig:MRS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In case of example image (which provide package `graphicx`) you will get:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, apparently i had included the usepackage 
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} 
so when i removed it it really dit work.. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle This is why a question always (almost-always) should have a minimum working example which can be used to reproduce the problem.